# device is not launched

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I need a new emulator in my android, I created this:

[image]

but when launched, it doesnt work:

```
[2013-01-14 09:36:31 - 3CBike] ------------------------------
[2013-01-14 09:36:31 - 3CBike] Android Launch!
[2013-01-14 09:36:31 - 3CBike] adb is running normally.
[2013-01-14 09:36:31 - 3CBike] Performing com.usualbike.cbike.SplashScreen activity launch
[2013-01-14 09:36:31 - 3CBike] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'android4' is not available. Launching new emulator.
[2013-01-14 09:36:31 - 3CBike] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'android4'
[2013-01-14 09:36:34 - Emulator] emulator: warning: opening audio input failed
[2013-01-14 09:36:34 - Emulator] 
[2013-01-14 09:36:34 - Emulator] emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
[2013-01-14 09:36:34 - Emulator] 
[2013-01-14 09:36:34 - 3CBike] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2013-01-14 09:36:34 - 3CBike] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
```

it is open but now are 09:59 and only this is shown

[image]

Do I have some mistake in the configuration?

Comment: Is your computer really slow and with a limited amount of memory? If that's the case, I'd suggest using a device instead.

Comment: no, my computer is quite good, I've never had memory problems, is for that I suposse its configuration problem

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things you can try since you've said your computer has a good enough configuration:

- Try changing some of the AVD's values, by adding more ram, increase
  SD card. (Window > Android SDK and AVD Manager > Edit the AVD)
- Try checking the "Snapshot" option when editing the AVD, it will save
  the last state and load that instead of a full boot.

Try mixing and matching.

The emulator takes ages to start on my laptop (not very good spec, but once it starts, it will run fine as long as I don't close it)

If none of the options above help you, you can try using virtual box as describe [here](http://www.nuxeo.com/blog/development/2011/10/speeding-up-the-android-emulator/). I haven't tried it myself, but seen it running, and it does boot up really quickly, and give you the same sort of functionality